# Responsive Webdesign: Dynamic height

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've got the following page as an example for a responsive layout: [flexible Grid](http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-flexible.html)

Now i want my own project to do the same as the images on this page. As the screensize decreases, the elements should resize, too.

For the width of those elements, everything works just fine. But their height won't change. 
I wonder how the author of the example page achieved this, as he doesn't even use a single height-attribute on his images.

Here is my code:

- HTML

  ```
  <div id="wrapper">  
  <ol>
      <li id="el-1" class="figure"><div class="element"><p class="heading">Lorem1</p></div></li>
      <li id="el-2" class="figure"><div class="element"><p class="heading">Lorem2</p></div></li>
      <li id="el-3" class="figure"><div class="element"><p class="heading">Lorem3</p></div></li>
      <li id="el-4" class="figure"><div class="element"><p class="heading">Lorem4</p></div></li>
      <li id="el-5" class="figure"><div class="element"><p class="heading">Lorem5</p></div></li>
      <li id="el-logo" class="figure"><div class="background"><p>LoremIpsum<br>Lorem</p></div></li>
      <li id="el-6" class="figure"><div class="element"><p class="heading">Lorem6</p></div></li>
      <li id="el-7" class="figure"><div class="element"><p class="heading">Lorem7</p></div></li>
      <li id="el-8" class="figure"><div class="element"><p class="heading">Lorem8</p></div></li>
      <li id="el-9" class="figure"><div class="element"><p class="heading">Lorem9</p></div></li>
      <li id="el-10" class="figure"><div class="element"><p class="heading">Lorem10</p></div></li>
  </ol>
  ```
- CSS

http://nopaste.info/d8a051e767.html

Comment: I forgot to delete the height: 200px attribute. This was only for testing

Comment: What is your problem? If you set a width to an image but no height, the image will resize with correct proportions.

Comment: This would explain the example page, but how do i apply the same effect on a non-image element?

Comment: You can't in that easy way… But I still don't got your problem/question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example page is using  images while you're not. Then you can't use it as an example. In your case, if you don't set any height to your divs, they will grow to make their content fit. So, to make them resize together you can either use a table or use a javascript (check matching column for example)

Comment: Thank you. So, can i conclude that there is no way to do this by css-only if i don't use images?
Also, what way would you recommend? Table or script?

Comment: I would recommend table if you just want to go for a grid with content at this point. No reason to load a script just for that. If you want to make it more complex and flexible in time, then you might need a bit of js.

Answer (score 0):

Its the

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

in ex-site-flexible.html line 63.

It makes the image as width as the containing A and images automatically scale correctly..

Other elements however do not, so you can only do this with images.